# Loop To Change Value In Matrix for Tic Tac Toe Game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making a Tic Tac Toe game and I do have working code and it does what I want it to do so far. I was just wondering if there was a way to shorten this function at all. My code is as follows...

```
def EnterMove(board):
    move = input("Enter your move (number between 1 - 9): ")

    if move == '1':
        board[0][0] = 'O'
    elif move == '2':
        board[0][1] = 'O'
    elif move == '3':
        board[0][2] = 'O'
    elif move == '4':
        board[1][0] = 'O'
    elif move == '5':
        board[1][1] = 'O'
    elif move == '6':
        board[1][2] = 'O'
    elif move == '7':
        board[2][0] = 'O'
    elif move == '8':
        board[2][1] = 'O'
    elif move == '9':
        board[2][2] = 'O'

#Making the playing board
board = []

for i in range(3):
    row = [Empty for i in range(3)]
    board.append(row)

board[0][0] = '1'
board[0][1] = '2'
board[0][2] = '3'
board[1][0] = '4'
board[1][1] = '5'
board[1][2] = '6'
board[2][0] = '7'
board[2][1] = '8'
board[2][2] = '9'
```

So like I said this all works just fine for what I want it to do so far, I was just wondering if there was an easier way to build the board and build the EnterMove function. Thanks so much.

(Note: The player move is going to be "O's" while the computer's will be "X's" and I'm just going to us pretty much the same code for the player move function, but just use `str(random.randint(1,9))` for it to decided the computer's move)

Comment: Questions about improving working code are more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Comment: Perhaps you should notice the mathematical pattern between the move number and the list indexes. Division and modulus will be useful there.

Comment: When initializing the board you can simply increment a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use division and modulo to obtain the rows and columns instead:

```
def EnterMove(board):
    move = int(input("Enter your move (number between 1 - 9): ")) - 1
    board[move // 3][move % 3] = 'O'

board = []

for i in range(3):
    row = [Empty for i in range(3)]
    board.append(row)

for i in range(9):
    board[i // 3][i % 3] = str(i + 1)
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't even think of this, thank you so much!